# Custom UIControl does not work with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uicontrol

When the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is not added to the view, both the `UIButton` and `CustomControl` will receive the `.touchUpInside` event. However, when the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is added to the view, only the `UIButton` can receive the `.touchUpInside` event. How can a custom `UIControl` be configured to respond to the touch event like `UIButton` in this scenario?

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        let uiButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        uiButton.backgroundColor = .red
        uiButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onUIButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(uiButton)
        
        let customButton = CustomControl(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        customButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCustomControlClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(customButton)
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func onTap() {
        debugPrint("onTap")
    }
    
    @objc func onUIButtonClick() {
        debugPrint("onUIButtonClick")
    }
    
    @objc func onCustomControlClick() {
        debugPrint("onCustomControlClick")
    }
}

class CustomControl: UIControl {
}
```

Comment: Update your question showing the relevant code from your `CustomControl` class. This would include anything related to events/touches/tracking/actions.

Comment: I've simplify my `CustomControl` to jus inherit from the `UIControl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate method [gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624213-gesturerecognizershouldbegin) asks if the gesture should read (and interrupt) touches. In your case:

```swift
class CustomControl: UIControl {
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return !(gestureRecognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

You can expand the conditional if you don't want other gestures to interrupt either.

Comment: Great find. I've been trying to override just about every method I can find in `UIResponder`, `UIView`, and `UIControl` and nothing was working. I missed this `UIView` method. This is exactly the right solution. `UIButton` overrides this to return `false` when the button is tapped. `UISlider` overrides this to return `false` only if the user taps on thumb and return `true` if the user taps outside of the thumb.